# Update MTU size for Bluetooth

Tags: c#, stm32, bluenrg

Background: I have written Embedded application running on a STM32 chip with BlueNRG_M0 Bluetooth(4.2) LE module. I have a C# windows Application that is the client and is reading data form the embedded(remote) device.
Problem Statement: The C# is only receiving 21 bytes of data while I am sending > 21 bytes from my embedded application
Tried: I have debugged my embedded application and I can see the buffer sizes are correct.
On the C# side I read the MaxPduSize, its 23 bytes.

Online resources frm microsoft say I cannot update the MaxPduSize, its a read only variable. It can only be changed from the remote aplication(server).

There is very little to no information on how to update the maxPduSize on the STM Ble chip.

Comment: I have no experience with any of this, but you would do well to boil this down to a [mcve] and show your code.

Comment: Please use a ble sniffer or use some hci logging tool and verify that the ATT MTU (it's this size that's important, not just any random buffer size) gets negotiated to fit your data. Or just check your code on the peripheral that this is set correctly.

Comment: I have verified on an independent application, and I get the correct data. So I'm not questioning the Embedded application.